# Cache for IO operation C#

Tags: c#, caching

We have windows services that run on different servers(that performa muliple IO operations based on the source value read) and we are looking into the capability of caching some of the IO results. This cached value should be accessible for other services within the same server and also other servers.

Windows services are written in .NET Core 2.1 , they are console applications wrapped using Topshelf to be uses as windows services.

any suggestion on what caching API that i can use to manage caches, specific to my situation.?

Comment: This is a bit too vague to be answerable in its present condition.  Can you be more specific about "caching some of the IO results"  and "muliple IO operations based on the source value read"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you have an IO operation that is too expensive, so you want to cache the results of the operation so that other processes within the server and other processes running on other servers can share it. is that right?

It's a complicated design question. We need to know what kind of results, we are talking about, size, etc.

At the bare minimum, you could use a database to store your "cache" data so other processes can access it. Then you need to worry about refreshing the cache and synchronizing with other processes, etc.

You could also think about [memory mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) which could be accessed by other processes. But you may need to provide some kind of API for other servers to access it.

Hope that helps you start somewhere.